# Merge multiple tsv/csv files or their contents in their respective columns separated by names and names order

Tags: bash, csv, unix, awk

I have files high-apple.tsv, low-apple.tsv, high-banana.tsv, low-banana.tsv, high-cherry.tsv, low-cherry.tsv. They all have columns green, blue, red and yellow.

I want to parse the contents of each file partially matching the file names. For example, I want to aggregate the file contents of high-apple followed by low-apple and so forth. I also want the file that are merged separated (or tagged) by their names so that I could know the part where it has come from.

order to aggregate:

```
high-apple.tsv                  

low-apple.tsv                   

high-banana.tsv                 

low-banana.tsv                  

high-cherry.tsv                 

low-cherry.tsv
```

Comment: note this is a too broad. Better [edit], show a [mcve] and what you tried so far. Otherwise we do not have enough information to help you.

Comment: @fedorqui Please see the edit.

Comment: Mmmm I am afraid it is still quite broad. An example can sometimes be a better explanation than a lot of text. Give a try to that so we know what is your goal here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming by aggregate you mean concatenate unchanged contents, something like this may work...

```
$ for f in apples bananas; do echo "contents of $f" >> fruits; cat $f >> fruits; done
```

the script concatenates the file contents with a header of "contents of {filename}".  If all your files are in the same format you don't need any other complexity.  You can list the files as "apples bananas ..." in the right order.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I need.